# Should read-only Ember computed properties be marked as @property or @method in YUIdoc?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, documentation, ember-cli, yuidoc

How should read-only computed properties (say, of Ember.js Models) be documented as, in YUIdoc?

Say I have a simple model:

```
/**
 * Person model
 * @class Person
 * @extends Ember.Object
 * @constructor
 */
Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  /**
   * @property firstName
   * @type String
   */
  firstName: null,

  /**
   * @property lastName
   * @type String
   */
  lastName: null,

  /**
   * ? what goes here?
   */
  fullName: Ember.computed('firstName', 'lastName', function() {
    return `${this.get('firstName')} ${this.get('lastName')}`;
  })
});
```

What should `fullName` be marked as?

Is it a `@property`? And if so, should it be marked as `@readOnly`? I can see it both ways -- since it doesn't have a setter function, it's a read-only property. On the other hand, it's derived from editable/settable properties, so it can change as a result of user actions.

Or is it a `@method`? Because it not only uses other properties, but actually transforms them? The transforms part isn't as obvious in such a simple example, but say a computed property was something like `nameInitials`, which only returned the first letters of the first & last name, etc?

Also: Am I correct to use the `@property` tag for Ember properties, and not the `@attribute` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: I think you should use this template:

```
@property name
@type {type}
@public/@private
```

As suggested by Gaurav add `@readOnly` if you use `.readOnly()` or `computed.readOnly()`, and `@default` if it has a default value (not `null` or `undefined`).

**Explanation:**

As for the `@method` question: no, please no! Look at it from the perspective of the consumer of your object (that's what your API docs are basically for). You cannot call `object.property()` as you would for a method. But as long as you use Ember's getters and setters (which you should always do), the CP behaves exactly as a static property. And the value of it is not the `Ember.ComputedProperty` instance, it is the value that this instance returns. So weather it is a CP or a static property is totally transparent to the consumer, and always should be, so you can change a static property to a computed one or vice versa at any time without breaking things!

And try to always specify the access keyword like `@public` or `@private`, as this helps to define and reason about the public API of your "thing". Only the public properties/methods may be used by the consumer of let`s say your component as well only those should be subject to unit or component integration tests, while you retain the freedom to always change your private stuff as long as the public API does not change.

And please, do *not* use the `@final` keyword. The docs might be a bit misleading there, but `final` is a pretty common keyword in other (classical object oriented) languages, that says that you *may not* override this property/method in a child class. So unless this is the case, don't use it.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you should have here:

```
@property fullName
@type String
@final
```

You should use `@final`, `@readonly` tag is only for `attributes`.

Comment: This seems correct, but are you sure about `@final`? The docs say 'the property is a constant and should not be changed'. But since it's a computed property, it changes all the time -- is the 'should not be changed' just referring to the fact that you can't change the computed property directly via `set()`?

Answer (score 0):

The ember.js source code uses @property, not @method.

Example: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/ae6c9e82b91fd5b695907e7b76c998a128a157d0/packages/ember-views/lib/views/text_field.js#L108

Comment: Thanks! Can you comment on whether to mark it `@readOnly`?

Comment: Also, the ember.js source code has counter-examples, that use @method, for computed properties: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js#L1523

Comment: I would mark it readonly only if you use .readonly() or Ember.computed.readonly